# ETIMEDOUT error when i connect remote mysql server with heroku NODE.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, node-mysql

I am using an **remotely hosted mysql db** in my Node.JS project. The connection works locally (with the remote mysql) and also when i host it on the same server as the mysql db. But gives me a **'ETIMEDOUT'** error when i try to connect it from **heroku**.

Here is my db script, where all the db related operations are

```
'use strict';
var utils = require('./utils');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = null;

exports.init = function (env) {
    if (env === 'production') {
        pool = mysql.createPool({
            host     : '100.00.00.109',
            user     : 'kjahsdkasd',
            password : 'asdasda!',
            database : 'maics'
        });
    } else {
        pool = mysql.createPool({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : '',
            database : 'maics'
        });
    }
};

exports.query = function (query, callback, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(error, connection){
        if (error) { 
            utils.error({
                data : error 
            }, "error in mysql connection", res);
        } else {
            connection.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) { 
                    utils.error({
                        data : err 
                    }, "error in mysql operation", res);
                }
                else callback(result, fields);
            });
        }
    });
};

exports.queryWithObject = function (query, object, callback, res) {

    pool.getConnection(function(error, connection){
        if (error) { 
            utils.error({
                data : error 
            }, "error in mysql connection", res);
        } else {
            connection.query(query, object, function (err, result, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) { 
                    utils.error({
                        data : err 
                    }, "error in mysql operation", res);
                }
                else callback(result, fields);
            });
        }

    });
};
```

**When i query, this is the response i get.**

[image: The Response]

This is my remote mysql configuration on the Server, i have allowed all the requests and it also works locally with the remote db. i know its a very specific issue, i am just looking for any directions.

[image]

Comment: Try setting the MySQL server to listen on `0.0.0.0` (if you haven't already).

Comment: Tried that @BenFortune, also i allowed all incoming ip's with the % wildcard, so that doesn't look like the problem

Comment: Hey did you ever end up figuring out the issue?